# Stop/Play on DIV show/hide HTML5 Video

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, video

You've all been so great in helping me in the past and I'm hoping we can solve this next problem as well.

I am building a slideshow of sorts using videos as backgrounds instead of images. Everything is working perfectly except that the timing of the videos is off because even though my divs are hidden the videos are all playing at the same time.

So, what I need is a JS/jQuery solution to stop (not pause) and play the videos as the divs are hidden/shown. Here's my code so far:

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Z2Nq8/1/

JS:

```
$(function () {

var counter = 0,
    divs = $('#video1, #video2, #video3');

function showDiv () {
    divs.hide() 
        .filter(function (index) { return index == counter % 3; }) // figure out correct div to show
        .show(); 

    counter++;
}; 

showDiv();     

setInterval(function () {
    showDiv(); 
}, 7 * 1000);     
});
```

HTML:

```
`<div id="videocont">
    <div id="video1" class="display">
        <video autoplay loop poster="PHI.png" id="bgvid">
        <source src="URL/video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
             <div id="title">Headline text.
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="video2" class="display">
        <video autoplay loop poster="PHI.png" id="bgvid">
        <source src="URL/video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
             <div id="title">Headline text.
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="video3" class="display">
        <video autoplay loop poster="PHI.png" id="bgvid">
        <source src="URL/video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
             <div id="title">Headline text.
        </div>
    </div>
</div>`
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have auto play on all of the videos.

Set auto play on the first element, then when you're going through the videos use:

```
VideoElement.play()
```

And

```
VideoElement.pause()
```

If you want to then reset the video you can do:

```
VideoElement.currentTime = 0;
```

To manage the videos playing.

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Z2Nq8/55/)

Comment: Do you still require help?

Comment: Sorry something has come up, I will definitely get this to you later though.

Comment: Hey, sorry I had 90% of it finished but lost the fiddle to a computer crash! I'll start on it again now.

Comment: @Shadna I updated my answer with a working example, sorry for the rushed code, I am in a rush :$. Gives you a working copy and you can easily refactor it to make it more elegant.

Comment: Everything is looking great in Chrome and Explorer! Thanks for the help! However, when I browser test in Safari it breaks. Videos disappear from view and the slideshow won't loop. Thoughts on a solution? @speak

Comment: Actually, doesn't work in Safari or Firefox. I'm working on a Mac OS 10.6. All browsers up to date.

Comment: Wow that's very strange. Can't think of anything that'll cause that large an error in other browsers... I will look into it!

Comment: If only everyone used Chrome. :P

Comment: Hey Shadna, really sorry but I don't have access to a Mac at all! I tested in IE 9+, Chrome, Firefox on Windows 8.1 and had no issues at all. Apologies that I can't help further, I had another look through the code and there's nothing I can see that would break in such modern browsers! :( Really hope you can find a fix for it.

Comment: I think it might have something to do with the video  coding or something. I'll keep looking. Glad to hear it's working on Windows! Thanks again for the help. @speak